# Why is the streamfunction constant at the boundary of a pipe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Consider a long cylindrical pipe rotating about its long axis with an imcompressible fluid inside.

Why is the streamfunction constant at the boundary inside the pipe?

Comment: I believe that this is a question for a physicist more than for a mathematician.

Comment: I think it's perfectly reasonable to imagine that a mathematician with a good knowledge of fluid dynamics can answer this.

Comment: I agree with you